# Possible to get individual polygons in a multipolygon?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, geography

I have a sql server table that has a column that contains [Geography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-2017) instances.  Some of these instances are [MultiPolygons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/multipolygon?view=sql-server-2017).

Is there any way to extract the individual polygons from a Multipolygon?

For example - if I have the following Multipolygon:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)), ((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35), (30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20)))
```

Would it be possible to get the individual polygons:

```
POLYGON((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40))
POLYGON((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35), (30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20))
```

using built in functions and without doing some sort of string parsing/regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Declare @MultiGeom Geometry
Set @MultiGeom = 'MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)), ((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35), (30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20)))'

DECLARE @n int = 1;

WHILE (@n <= @MultiGeom.STNumGeometries())
   BEGIN
      Print Convert(VarChar(4000), (@MultiGeom.STGeometryN(@n)))
   SET @n = @n + 1;
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

A riff off of the accepted answer that is set-based. Assuming that you have a numbers table (look [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/creative-solutions-by-using-a-number-table/) for what this is and other examples where this might be useful), you can do something like this:

```
declare @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('
    MULTIPOLYGON (
        ((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)), 
        ((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35), (30 20, 20 15, 20 25, 30 20))
    )', 0);

select @g.STGeometryN(n.n).ToString()
from dbo.Numbers as n
where n <= @g.STNumGeometries();
```